# speechsythesisutterance is not working after chrome update

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have implemented text to speech in javascript it is a funtion which create speech back to back process for different message. sometime before it was working fine but after updating chrome (auto update of window) it doesn't work so i have used artyom library which was also working fine. but now after update of windows again it does support speech again..
now both of the library is not support text to speech.. please help me somebody.. was stuck in this from last 1 month many times it work and after update it doen't i am not getting any standard solution please help...

```
        
            if ( 'speechSynthesis' in window ) 
            {
                window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
                 //$(".divRandom").hide();
                let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);             
                voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                
                if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
                    speech_voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
                    speech_voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
                    };
                }
                
                speech.voice = speech_voices[1];
                
                //speech.lang = "en-US";
                speech.volume = 2;
                if (speed > 1)
                    speech.rate = 3;//slow speaking
                else
                    speech.rate = 7;//faster
                
                speech.pitch = 1;
                
                
                window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
            }
            else
            {
                /*var Jarvis = new Artyom();
            
                Jarvis.ArtyomVoicesIdentifiers["en-GB"] = ["Google UK English Female", "Google UK English Male", "en-GB", "en_GB"];
                //Jarvis.say(msg);
                //Jarvis.ArtyomProperties["speed"] = 3;
            
                Jarvis.say(msg.toString(),{
                onStart:function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    // Most likely to be true
                    console.log("Speaking : "+ Jarvis.isSpeaking().toString());
                    },500);
                },
                onEnd: function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    // Most likely to be false
                    console.log("Speaking : "+ Jarvis.isSpeaking().toString());
                    },500);
                    }
                });*/
                alert("your browser doesn't support audio..");
            }
```

Comment: Try commenting out the speed, volume and pitch changes. speech_voices[1] may have changed between versions.

Comment: thanks frazer.. it is working but back to back speech is overlapping and doesn't complete the speech.. so i need to make it faster is there any other solution to make speech faster ??

Comment: Comment out the cancel() and the speech utterances will queue.

Comment: but what about speed?? want faster speech.. if i am usinng rate property chrome will not speak it..

Comment: Play with the numbers and voice[number] until it works e.g. voice[1] might work with speed = 4 or 6, or another voice might work with speed 3 and 7.